# where's the error im missing? odd fibonacci numbers

Tags: javascript, algorithm, while-loop, fibonacci

It's a function that returns the sum of all of the odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to the given number.

I am stuck with the last of the tests, all of them work besides this one.
sumFibs(75025) should return 135721, I've been trying many things but none worked.

```js
function sumFibs(num) {

  let f1 = 1;
  let f2 = 1;
  let fiboNums = [];

  while (f1 <= num && f2 <= num) {
    if (f1 % 2 !== 0) fiboNums.push(f1);
    if (f2 % 2 !== 0) fiboNums.push(f2);
    f1 += f2;
    f2 += f1;
  }

  return fiboNums.reduce((pV, cV) => pV + cV);
}

console.log(sumFibs(75025));
```

Instructions: Given a positive integer num, return the sum of all odd Fibonacci numbers that are less than or equal to num.

The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 and 1. Every additional number in the sequence is the sum of the two previous numbers. The first six numbers of the Fibonacci sequence are 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 and 8.

For example, sumFibs(10) should return 10 because all odd Fibonacci numbers less than or equal to 10 are 1, 1, 3, and 5.

I tried changing the boolean statement of the while loop as well as the if-statements by adding a condition that evaluates to true if f1 or f2 are less than or equal to the given number

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post to ask a clear, specific question in sentence format. Also take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the original problem? OK, it's at https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/sum-all-odd-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: "while (f1 <= num && f2 <= num)" You're ignoring f1 when f1 <= num but f2 > num. You can do a final check at the end to cover this case.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that once `f2` is bigger than `num`, the loop ends even though `f1` is not bigger than `num`, therefore skipping the last relevant number in the series and excluding it from the results. Here's a revised version that fixes the problem:

```js
function sumFibs(num) {

  let f1 = 1;
  let f2 = 1;
  let fiboNums = [];

  while (f1 <= num) {
    if (f1 % 2 !== 0) fiboNums.push(f1);
    if (f2 <= num && f2 % 2 !== 0) fiboNums.push(f2);
    f1 += f2;
    f2 += f1;
  }

  return fiboNums.reduce((pV, cV) => pV + cV);
}

console.log(sumFibs(75025));
```

Comment: Thanks Noam, I appreciate your help, I was really struggling on that logic, now it makes sense:)